# Are Javascript timers released when using them in recursive function?

Tags: javascript, recursion, settimeout

I came across the code below where `setTimeout` is called recursively until `window.value` is not nullable:

```
const process = () => {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    (function checkScriptParsed(self) {
      self.timer = window.setTimeout(() => {
        if (window.value) {
          clearTimeout(self.timer);
          resolve();
        } else {
          checkScriptParsed(self);
        }
      }, 50);
    })({});
  });
};
```

My question is that in case `window.value` becomes not nullable 50ms after 00:00:00 and one timer is generated each millisecond, will there be 49 active timers running at 50ms after 00:00:00?

Comment: No there will be one timer at a time. This code checks script parsed every 50 second. If it would be 1 ms, then there would be 1 timer every 1ms. What's important is that 50ms is idle time between function calls. Function execution time also adds up.

Comment: Additionally, there is almost always a better way to wait for a variable. You probably should add why you would even use that code in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is only one timer active at a time because `setTimeout` is a one-shot: unlike `setInterval` is does not start itself again. In fact, this line

```
clearTimeout(self.timer);
```

is rubbish because when called the timer has finished and doesn't need clearing.

The code appears to be an overly complicated version of something like

```
const process = () => {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    const timer = setInterval( () => {
      if (window.value) {
        clearInterval(timer);
        resolve();
      } 
     }, 50);
  });
};
```

Even so, a `load` event handler on an asynchronously loaded script may be a better way of detecting if a script has been parsed.